# What concept is at work here and where can it be applied?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
   static int x;
   return x;
}   

int main()
{
   fun() = 10;
   cout<<fun();
   return 0;
}
```

The above program outputs 10. But I am confused as to how this program actually works.

Comment: Because `x` is a static variable, it doesn't "stop existing" when the function ends. Hence, it's okay to return a pointer or reference to it. After that it's just basic reference behavior !

Comment: What's the practical value of writing something like this?

Comment: @Panzercrisis (That's what I'm asking. The only use case I've found valid and reasonable so far was overloading `operator[]` on a class so one can write `obj[idx] = value;`... But as-is, this is just horrible.)

Comment: @Panzercrisis For normal functions it works great as convenience adaptor. `int& get(int x, int y) { return v[x*sizey+x]; }`

Comment: @Panzercrisis Well, that is my question exactly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz In this example, I don't see how this would be any better than simply declaring x as a global variable, only how it would be worse.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I just came across this code somewhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fun()` returns reference of a static variable `x`, in first expression in `main()`:

```
 fun() = 10;
  ^       ^
  |       x assigned 10
   returned x
```

Because static variable's value persists between different function calls, so in next expression:

```
cout << fun();
           ^
           return x with value 10
```

Note: Because your are returning reference of a static variable so its not an undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 but to precise the last line a bit: it wouldn't be UB if it didn't return a reference - it would simply fail to compile.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think what Grijesh meant was "it would be UB if the variable wasn't `static`"

Comment: @Angew yes! did I wrote confusing? @ H2Co3 please check my English :)

Comment: @amulous note: this code is *correct* because you returns reference of *static* variable, if you might sent reference of simple(local) variable that would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes. I understand that @Girijesh.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nah, it was just me misinterpreting it.

Comment: @H2CO3 My English given me many downvotes these days :), Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have a static int variable inside the function fun().
The function returns a reference to that variable.
You assign 10 to the variable.
You print the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function returns a reference, it's possible to modify the underlying static variable.

On the first call, the `static int` variable is created, and then reference to it is returned. Then you set the value of the `x` to 10.

The `cout` statement obtains the reference again and uses it to write `x` to stdout.

It's worth noting that if `x` wasn't `static`, it would be destroyed at the end of function scope, and returned reference would be a *reference to temporary*, which is illegal.

---

The most common practical application is `operator[]`

```
class ArrayWrapper {
    int v [100];

public:
    int& operator[] (int index) { 
        return v[index];
    }
};

// usage:
ArrayWrapper aw;
aw[3] = 3;
cout << aw[10];
```

Of course this is an example implementation; for real world overloaded `op[]` look at `std::vector` or `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

`fun` will return a reference to the static variable `x`, which can then be used to modify the value of `x`. The C equivalent might be something like:

```
int *fun()
{
    static int x;
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = fun();
    *ptr = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *fun());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote the C equivalent too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning a reference to a static variable. Static variables continue to exist after the function has exited.

Since the function returns a reference, you're able to set that value, and then it's output to the screen. It's basically "hiding" a global variable. I'm not sure where it makes a lot of sense to use this technique, however...

Answer (score 0):

a reference to the static variable x in f is being used to assign the value 10 to x; it (the reference) is then being passed to cout

Answer (score 0):

a static variable is essentially a global that can only be accessed directly from a single function. when your function returns a reference to this variable, it in fact returns its address. Since the variable is global, it is always the same address, therefore your function is in fact giving everyone access to this variable.